# Iterate Rasters will not connect to the Raster Calcuator tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, arcgis-10.5, iterator

Using ArcGIS Desktop, 10.5.1 I need to iterate through hundreds of FGDB rasters (single band, 16-bit, unsigned) that are stored in a single FGDB.  I need to modify each iterated raster with the Raster Calculator and output the resulting raster to a different FGDB.

**The problem:** I cannot "connect" the Iterate Rasters output to the Raster Calculator tool as an *input*.  As shown in the image below, there is no input option:

[image]

**Weirdly, I got the model to work if:**

1. I add the Raster Calculator tool without attempting to connect
2. I input the Raster Calculator values, as shown below
3. I hardcode the source FGDB path, as highlighted below (without the hardcoded path, the dreaded 000539 error occurs!?!?!?)

Arc then automatically connects the Iterator to the Raster Calculator, *but through the Name bubble*.  I thought that the connection always had to be from the "green bubble"!?

Why can't I connect the iterator to the Raster Calculator as an input?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The specific condition (i.e., exceptions as named it) of this tool as connecting the variables is explained in [the respective help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) as follows:

> The Raster Calculator tool generally follows the standard connectivity
> behavior of models in ModelBuilder, with some exceptions resulting
> from the requirements of formulating a valid Map Algebra expression.
> These include the following:
>
> - Variables are connected to the Raster
>   Calculator tool **when they are selected from the list of variables**. All
>   variables are automatically listed in the Variable list inside the
>   tool.
> - When a dataset or variable is used in the expression, a link
>   between the variable and the tool will be created. If you remove the
>   variable from the expression, the associated link between the variable
>   and the tool will also be removed.
> - If you **delete the connection** to a
>   variable, the variable is **not removed** from the expression.
> - You **should
>   not rename a variable** that is connected to the tool, since the
>   variable will not be renamed within the expression. If you do so, the
>   expression will be invalid.

Comment: I'm back after a long absence.  Unfortunately, the ESRI help page is rather ambiguous, so I'm still confused... is my OP approach correct?